# Issue with flashing gapps in CM13 for OnePlusOne (bacon)

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom-flashing, 6.0-marshmallow, oneplus-one

I am having issues with flashing gapps using cyanogenmod recovery. I installed cyanogenmod nightly (with recovery) from http://download.cyanogenmod.org/?device=bacon dated 14/12/2015.

It installed perfectly. I installed few apks. Works fine. The problem is that when i try to flash the `open_gapps-arm-6.0-nano-20151216` from [here](https://github.com/opengapps/arm/releases) from  dated 20151216 , it fails.

I get the following stacktrace in /tmp/recovery.log -

```
[   11.520607] Now send the package you want to apply
[   11.520618] to the device with "adb sideload <filename>"...
[   12.521723] unknown fuse request opcode 22
[   12.531326] Finding update package...
[   12.539084] I:Update location: /sideload/package.zip
[   12.539130] Opening update package...
[   12.539486] I:read key e=3 hash=20
[   12.539674] I:read key e=65537 hash=20
[   12.539862] I:read key e=65537 hash=20
[   12.540054] I:read key e=65537 hash=20
[   12.540095] I:4 key(s) loaded from /res/keys
[   12.540130] Verifying update package...
[   12.557402] I:comment is 1357 bytes; signature 1339 bytes from end
[   23.136467] I:whole-file signature verified against RSA key 0
[   23.136519] I:verify_file returned 0
[   23.136588] Installing update...
[   23.137612] E:Can't run /tmp/update_binary (No such file or directory)
[   23.138304] E:Installation error in /sideload/package.zip
[   23.138317] (Status 255)
[   23.138355]
[   25.195878] sideload-host file size 67337561 block size 65536
[   25.195904] sideload_host finished
[   25.196913] I:sideload thread finished
[   25.197182] Restarting adbd...
[   25.197603] Installation aborted.
```

But I can verify that /tmp/update_binary exists.

executing `ls -la /tmp/update_binary` returns -

```
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for localtime!
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for GMT!
__bionic_open_tzdata: couldn't find any tzdata when looking for posixrules!
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 60190 1970-04-26 13:02 /tmp/update_binary
```

`du -hs /tmp/update_binary`  returns --

```
60K /tmp/update_binary
```

I have no clue on how to proceed next. Does anybody here have a fix? I want gapps installed on my device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try replacing the CM recovery with TRWP and flash open_gapps with that. My OnePlusOne has TWRP and flashing open_gapps worked fine. 
The disadvantage is that you have to reboot into recovery to flash the CM updates.

Comment: I've been able to update with TWRP without booting into recovery. I couldn't with CM12, but it works again with CM13.

Comment: You're right. It works for me again too.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to to keep the CM recovery and load Open GApps as long as I side-loaded both of them at the same time using `adb`. In other words, load **both** the CM `.zip` and the Open GApps `.zip` before you reboot.